# conflicting declaration 'printPolarForm c'

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I wanted to declare a constructor but I face this error. As it's obvious , I wanted to create a program to show the polar form of a complex number. I know it's kind of ridiculous and it's easier to do this , with functions . BUT this is a project and it is mentioned not to change the body of main function.

How can this be fixed?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
public:
    double real , img;


    Complex()
    {
        real = 0;
        img = 0;
    }
};


class constructComplex : public Complex
{
public:
    constructComplex(double a , double b)
    {
        real = a;
        img = b;
    }
};

class printPolarForm : public Complex
{
public:
    printPolarForm(Complex z)
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
        double r = sqrt( z.real * z.real + z.img * z.img );
        double argument = atan2(z.img , z.real)*180/3.14;
        cout << r << "e^(i" << argument << ')';
    }
};




int main()
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    double x1, y1;
    cin >> x1 >> y1;
    Complex c = constructComplex(x1, y1);
    printPolarForm(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `printPolarForm` a class at all? For that matter, why is `constructComplex`?

Comment: The actual error you're getting is that it thinks that you're trying to declare a variable of type `printPolarForm` whose name is `c`, and that conflicts with the fact that `c` is already a variable of type `Complex`. You can do various things like "give this new variable its own name, instead of making it an anonymous temporary" or "use {} instead of () so it understands it's a temporary", but ultimately the real question is why are these classes instead of free functions?

Comment: Can you please add the full compiler output? The next person searching for that error will then have a better chance at finding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a serious misunderstanding of what classes are for. Generally speaking classes encapsulate some *state*, i.e. member variables, and some operations on that state. None of your last two classes above have any state beyond the `Complex` class that they inherit from, so they should not exist as classes.

Let's see how this code should be written

`constructComplex` is an attempt to construct a complex number from parameters, so it should be an alternate constructor within the `Complex` class. i.e.

```
class Complex
{
public:
    double real , img;

    Complex()
    {
        real = 0;
        img = 0;
    }

    Complex(double a, double b)
    {
        real = a;
        img = b;
    }
};
```

With this new constructor your `main` code changes from

```
Complex c = constructComplex(x1, y1);
```

to

```
Complex c(x1, y1);
```

`printPolarForm` is an operation on an existing complex number. It could be defined as a member function or a free function. I'll show that as a free function first

```
void printPolarForm(Complex z)
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    double r = sqrt( z.real * z.real + z.img * z.img );
    double argument = atan2(z.img , z.real)*180/3.14;
    cout << r << "e^(i" << argument << ')';
}
```

the alternative is to make is a member function of the `Complex` class

```
class Complex
{
    ...

    void printPolarForm() const
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
        double r = sqrt( real * real + img * img );
        double argument = atan2(img , real)*180/3.14;
        cout << r << "e^(i" << argument << ')';
    }
};
```

The rest of the `Complex` class is as before. With the member function method you have to change how the function is called in `main`. Instead of

```
printPolarForm(c);
```

you would write

```
c.printPolarForm();
```

Either of these two options (free function or member function) are perfectly acceptable in this case. In both cases the class `printPolarForm` has been removed.